# How to obtain CAN transmitted data (256 bytes)using Diagnostic functions using CAPL?

Tags: c++, can-bus, diagnostics, capl, canoe

256 bytes of data is transmitted to CAN bus as response to a particular DID. It consists of 14 samples of data AND one sample consists of 12 bytes of data (10 different values of 10 different variables packed across 12 bytes). I need to collect these different samples with the help of CAPL using diagnostic functions.

Comment: Show your code please. Why is this tagged with C++? 14*12=168<>256.

Comment: I haven't developed the code yet. all the unused bytes are transmitted as 00. and Honestly I was searching for a solution/logic thay why I tagged c++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use diagGetPrimitiveData or diagGetPrimitiveByte for raw data. Details and example you can find in CANoe help

For reading parameters defined e.g. in .cdd you can use diagGetParameter